# how can we use data received through axios put request on client side in mern stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, mern

I have sent category Id to the Nodejs through this code

```
const catHandler = async (catId) => {
    const data =  Axios.put('/api/products/categories/filter',  {catId: catId},
        { 
            "headers": { "content-type": "application/json", },
        }
    ).then( categoriesProducts => {
        console.log(categoriesProducts.data.products)
    })
}
```

and this is my route for this

```
router.put('/categories/filter', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const findCategory = await Category.find({ _id: req.body.catId });
        if (findCategory) {
            const productsByCategory = await Product.find(
                { category: req.body.catId }
            ).then(products => {
                res.status(200).json({ products });
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('categories filter error', error)
    }
})
```

The products of specific category are being shown in the `console.log(categoriesProducts.data.products)` on the react front end side like below

```
0: {_id: "5f7c88756746363148792982", name: "Simple Pizza", price: 5.6, image: "1601996916374.jpg", countInStock: 434, …}
1: {_id: "5f7c88976746363148792983", name: "Smoked Pizza", price: 7.8, image: "1601996951114.jpg", countInStock: 88, …}
2: {_id: "5f7c88c56746363148792984", name: "Large Cheezy Pizza", price: 9.4, image: "1601996997474.jpg", countInStock: 434, …}
```

But I want to display these products on the front end side. I have tried to use axios.get method but with get method how can I can send category Id to backend. So if any one has any idea how to do that Plz guide me.

Comment: If you need to send a data using get request use queries

Answer (score 0):

you can use the query params with get method in node js
you can get query params by `req.query` in nodeJs

example
passing category id from front end -

```
api/products/categories/filter?cid=1
```

getting query param in the backend

```
const catId = req.query.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to pass parameter to API get method.

```
fetch("/api/products/categories/filter?catId" + catId)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => {
    this.setState({
      Items: json,
    });
  });
```

And also you first create new state named as Items such as below.

```
this.state = {
  Items: []
};
```

And finally Iterate on Items.

BR

Comment: how can I use state in the functional component? and I cannot change the functional component into class component bcz I am using useEffect hook? So what should I do now?

Comment: You can create a Class component wrapper over it. Pass it as props